# Strided vs shuffling reduction

Tags: c++, cuda

I've recently the watched CppCon talk about using Clang to compile CUDA cuda code, where the speaker after talking a bit about the architecture implements a sum reduction. I was interested in the approach he took which was doing a reduction by a shfl of the elements in the block, so with no working example I used his code modified it a little bit and got a max-reduction.

The thing is that this max reduction is very slow, compared to a CPU implementation of finding the max in 2^22 elements I get times of about ~90ms against ~20ms. Here is the code for the shfl reduction

```
#include <vector>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

using namespace std;

// Global reduce test
__global__ void d_max_reduce(const int *in, int *out, size_t N) {
    int sum = 0;
    size_t start = (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) * 4;
    for (size_t i = start; i < start + 4 && i < N; i++) {
        sum = max(__ldg(in + i), sum);
    }

    for (int i = 16; i; i >>= 1) {
        sum = max(__shfl_down(sum, i), sum);
    }

    __shared__ int shared_max;
    shared_max = 0;
    __syncthreads();

    if (!(threadIdx.x % 32)) {
        atomicMax(&shared_max, sum);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if (!threadIdx.x) {
        atomicMax(out, shared_max);
    }
}

int test_max_reduce(std::vector<int> &v) {
    int *in, *out;

    cudaMalloc(&in, v.size() * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&out, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(in, v.data(), v.size() * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemset(out, 0, sizeof(int));

    int threads = 256;
    d_max_reduce<<<ceil((float)v.size() / (threads * 4)), threads>>>(in, out, v.size());

    int res;
    cudaMemcpy(&res, out, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(in);
    cudaFree(out);
    return res;
}
```

So I used one of Nvidia's examples of a strided reduction (which is also is a sum) changed it to a max and I got times of about 7ms. Here is the code for the strided reduction

```
#include <vector>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

__global__ void d_max_reduction(const int *in, int *out, size_t N) {
    extern __shared__ int s_data[];

    size_t tid = threadIdx.x;
    size_t i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < N)
        s_data[tid] = in[i];
    else
        s_data[tid] = 0;
    __syncthreads();

    for (size_t s = blockDim.x / 2; s > 0; s >>= 1) {
        if (tid < s)
            s_data[tid] = max(s_data[tid], s_data[tid + s]);
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (!tid)
        atomicMax(out, s_data[0]);
}

int test_max_reduction(std::vector<int> &v) {
    int *in;
    int *out;

    cudaMalloc(&in, v.size() * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&out, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(in, v.data(), v.size() * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemset(out, 0, sizeof(int));

    int threads = 128;

    d_max_reduction<<<ceil((float)v.size() / threads),
                      threads,
                      threads * sizeof(int)>>>(in, out, v.size());

    int res;
    cudaMemcpy(&res, out, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(in);
    cudaFree(out);

    return res;
}
```

And just in case the rest so there is a MWE.

```
#include <random>
#include <timer.hpp>

int test_max_reduce(std::vector<int> &v);
int test_max_reduction(std::vector<int> &v);

int main() {
    int N = 2000 * 2000; // * 2000;
    std::vector<int> vec(N);

    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 mt(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, N << 2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        vec[i] = dist(mt);
    }


    measure("GPU (shfl)", test_max_reduce, vec);
    measure("GPU strided", test_max_reduction, vec);
    measure("CPU",
            [](std::vector<int> &vec) -> int {
                int maximum = 0;
                for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
                    maximum = std::max(maximum, vec[i]);
                }
                return maximum;
            },
            vec);

    return 0;
}
```

And timer.hpp is

```
#ifndef TIMER_HPP
#define TIMER_HPP

#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename F, typename ...Args>
void measure(std::string msg, F func, Args&&... args) {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    int val = func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << msg << " Test " << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Max Value : " << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Time      : ";
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
                 (end - start).count() << std::endl;
}

#endif // TIMER_HPP
```

I generally get the following times

```
GPU (shfl) Test 
 Max Value : 15999999
 Time      : 86
GPU strided Test 
 Max Value : 15999999
 Time      : 7
CPU Test 
 Max Value : 15999999
 Time      : 23
```

EDIT new timings after warmup

```
GPU (shfl) Test 
 Max Value : 16000000
 Time      : 4
GPU strided Test 
 Max Value : 16000000
 Time      : 6
CPU Test 
 Max Value : 16000000
 Time      : 23
```

So my more general question is why is the shfl version slower than the strided? Which can be divided in

Am I missing something in the launch parameters/doing/assumed something wrong?

And when is recommended to use shfl intrinsic over a strided loop and viceversa?

Comment: I think you're getting CUDA start-up overhead in your first timing measurement.  You're not following good benchmark techniques.  After you've done a warm-up of all 3 methods, re-run each and do your timing there.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Tested it, you were absolutely right, thanks!.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want.  I would upvote a sensible answer.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I would prefer to accept your answer :).

Comment: Note that performance of a good implementation of such a reduction is purely memory bandwidth limited, apart from some constant overhead at the beginning and end. So the effort should be spent on maximising memory throughput by using coalesced memory reads of the largest supported size (`int4`), and expanding the reduction loop over those so that the final reduction over all threads becomes negligible for large arrays.